# Convert </br> to end line

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract some text using `BeautifulSoup`. I'm using `get_text()` function for this purpose.

My problem is that the text contains `</br>` tags and I need to convert them to end lines. how can I do this?

Comment: I know this is 10 years old but did you mean `<br/>` and not `</br>`? I'd simply edit it but since there is a possibility that you actually mean broken `</br>` tags (and were misunderstood by the answerers), I though I'd ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regex should do the trick.

```
import re
s = re.sub('<br\s*?>', '\n', yourTextHere)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will fail to convert self-closing tags

Answer (score 92):

You can do this using the BeautifulSoup object itself, or any element of it:

```
for br in soup.find_all("br"):
    br.replace_with("\n")
```

Comment: the benefit of this answer is, that you can call `soup.text` afterwards to remove other html tags, whereas the currently accepted answer doesn't provide that possibility.

Comment: Watch out for this, you may end up losing some contents unintentionally. You may need to do something like `br.replace_with("\n" + br.text)`. This tag is evil...

Answer (score 70):

As [official doc](http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=get_text#get-text) says:

> You can specify a string to be used to join the bits of text together: soup.get_text("\n")

Comment: Seems that "bits of text" are words, not lines, so this would add a newline between each 2 words.

Comment: @Sasha I'm not sure what you mean by that -- I believe "bits of text" refers to text separated by tags. I am certainly not getting a newline between each pair of words when I run it, as you suggest.

Answer (score 9):

Also you can use ‍‍‍`get_text(separator = '\n', strip = True)` :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
bs=BeautifulSoup('<td>some text<br>some more text</td>','html.parser')
text=bs.get_text(separator = '\n', strip = True)
print(text)
 >> 
some text
some more text
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Ian's and dividebyzero's post/comments you can do this **to efficiently filter/replace *many* tags in one go**:

```
for elem in soup.find_all(["a", "p", "div", "h3", "br"]):
    elem.replace_with(elem.text + "\n\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the tags with \n, it may be better to just add a \n to the end of all of the tags that matter.

To steal the list from @petezurich:

```
for elem in soup.find_all(["a", "p", "div", "h3", "br"]):
    elem.append('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call `element.text` you'll get the text without br tags. 
Maybe you need define your own custom method for this purpose:

```
     def clean_text(elem):
        text = ''
        for e in elem.descendants:
            if isinstance(e, str):
                text += e.strip()
            elif e.name == 'br' or e.name == 'p':
                text += '\n'
        return text

    # get page content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request_response.text, 'html.parser')
    # get your target element
    description_div = soup.select_one('.description-class')
    # clean the data
    print(clean_text(description_div))
```