# How do I use BeautifulSoup4 to get ALL text before <br> tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape some data for my app. My question is I need some 
Here is the HTML code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    This
    <a class="tip info" href="blablablablabla">is a first</a>
    sentence.
    <br>
    This
    <a class="tip info" href="blablablablabla">is a second</a>
    sentence.
    <br>This
    <a class="tip info" href="blablablablabla">is a third</a>
    sentence.
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want output to looks like

> This is a first sentence.
>   This is a second sentence.
>   This is a third sentence.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Have you tried the below solutions? People are trying to solve your issue but you don't even care to respond @user4937980!!

Comment: Sorry I just woke up for hours. Finally I used SIM's method and it just work like a boss. All below solutions are brilliant. BTW web-Scraping is really hard to learn :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should give you the desired output. Just consider the `content` variable used within the below script to be the holder of your above pasted `html elements`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
items = ','.join([''.join([item.previous_sibling,item.text,item.next_sibling]) for item in soup.select(".tip.info")])
data = ' '.join(items.split()).replace(",","\n")
print(data)
```

Output:

```
This is a first sentence. 
This is a second sentence. 
This is a third sentence.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible. I'll answer in slightly greater generality because I doubt that you want merely to process that chunk of HTML.

First, get a pointer to the `td` element,

```
td = soup.find('td')
```

Now, notice that you can get a list of this element's children,

```
>>> td_kids = list(td.children)
>>> td_kids
['\n    This\n    ', <a class="tip info" href="blablablablabla">is a first</a>, '\n    sentence.\n    ', <br/>, '\n    This\n    ', <a class="tip info" href="blablablablabla">is a second</a>, '\n    sentence.\n    ', <br/>, 'This\n    ', <a class="tip info" href="blablablablabla">is a third</a>, '\n    sentence.\n    ', <br/>, '\n']
```

Some of the items in this list are string, some are HTML elements. Crucially, some are `br` elements.

You could split the list first of all into one or more lists by looking for,

```
isinstance(td_kid[<some k>], bs4.element.Tag)
```

for each item in the list.

Then, you could go through each of the sublists repeatedly replacing tags by turning them into soup and then getting the lists of children for these. Eventually, you will have several sublists containing only what BeautifulSoup calls 'navigable strings' that you can manipulate as usual.

Join the elements together, then I would suggest that you eliminate white space using a regex `sub` like this:

```
result = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', '', <joined list>)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
htmlText = """<tr>
  <td>
    This
    <a class="tip info" href="blablablablabla">is a first</a>
    sentence.
    <br>
    This
    <a class="tip info" href="blablablablabla">is a second</a>
    sentence.
    <br>This
    <a class="tip info" href="blablablablabla">is a third</a>
    sentence.
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# these two steps are to put everything into one line. may not be necessary for you
htmlText = htmlText.replace("\n", " ")
while "  " in htmlText:
    htmlText = htmlText.replace("  ", " ")

# import into bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText, "lxml")

# using https://stackoverflow.com/a/34640357/5702157
for br in soup.find_all("br"):
    br.replace_with("\n")

parsedText = soup.get_text()
while "\n " in parsedText:
    parsedText = parsedText.replace("\n ", "\n") # remove spaces at the start of new lines
print(parsedText.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and basic string manipulation like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''
<tr>
  <td>
    This
    <a class="tip info" href="blablablablabla">is a first</a>
    sentence.
    <br>
    This
    <a class="tip info" href="blablablablabla">is a second</a>
    sentence.
    <br>This
    <a class="tip info" href="blablablablabla">is a third</a>
    sentence.
    <br>
  </td>
</tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('td'):
    print ' '.join(i.text.split()).replace('. ', '.\n')
```

This will give as output:

```
This is a first sentence.
This is a second sentence.
This is a third sentence.
```

Comment: @novice-coder yes, I know - but web-scraping depends a lot on the content format (in this case the OP wants full sentences - thus the dot). Anyway This can be easily fixed by the OP depending on the actual content. The important thing in this answer is `i.text` since many programmers tend to forget or ignore it even exist!