# Extract Text from <p> element over <br> elements

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a script using `BeautifulSoup` to extract text from `<p>` elements; it works well until I encounter a `<p>` element that contains `<br>` tags, in which case it only captures the text BEFORE the first `<br>` tag. How can I edit my code to capture all of the text?

My code:

```
coms = soup.select('li > div[class=comments]')[0].select('p')
inp = [i.find(text=True).lstrip().rstrip() for i in coms]
```

The problem HTML (note the `<br>` tags):

```
<p>             
                    Alts called now through 53. No more will be called til the 12:50 group. EMCs are still on the table to be seen.<br>
<br>
ITR info:<br>
<br>
Rachel Hoffman, CD<br>
Chris Kory, acc.<br>
<br>
Monitor is Iftiaz Haroon.                </p>
```

What my code currently outputs:

```
>> 'Alts called now through 53. No more will be called til the 12:50 group. EMCs are still on the table to be seen.'
```

What my code SHOULD output (note the extra text):

```
>> 'Alts called now through 53. No more will be called til the 12:50 group. EMCs are still on the table to be seen. ITR info: Rachel Hoffman, CD Chris Kory, acc. Monitor is Iftiaz Haroon.'
```

(**Note**: Forgive my sometimes-questionable terminology; I'm largely self-taught.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup: just get inside of a tag, no matter how many enclosing tags there are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957013/beautifulsoup-just-get-inside-of-a-tag-no-matter-how-many-enclosing-tags-there)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use BeautifulSoup4 to get ALL text before <br> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48722571/how-do-i-use-beautifulsoup4-to-get-all-text-before-br-tag)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this question might be ill-framed. I copied the HTML into a file then ran the following code:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('matthew.htm').read(), 'lxml')
>>> soup.find('p').text
'             \n                    Alts called now through 53. No more will be called til the 12:50 group. EMCs are still on the table to be seen.\n\nITR info:\n\nRachel Hoffman, CD\nChris Kory, acc.\n\nMonitor is Iftiaz Haroon.                '
```

Obviously it's a simple matter to recover the required text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`get_text(strip=True)`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text).

From the documentation:

> If you only want the text part of a document or tag, you can use the `get_text()` method. It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string.
>
> You can tell Beautiful Soup to strip whitespace from the beginning and end of each bit of text using `strip=True`.

```
html = '''<p>             
                    Alts called now through 53. No more will be called til the 12:50 group. EMCs are still on the table to be seen.<br>
<br>
ITR info:<br>
<br>
Rachel Hoffman, CD<br>
Chris Kory, acc.<br>
<br>
Monitor is Iftiaz Haroon.                </p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('p').get_text(strip=True))
```

Output:

```
Alts called now through 53. No more will be called til the 12:50 group. EMCs are still on the table to be seen.ITR info:Rachel Hoffman, CDChris Kory, acc.Monitor is Iftiaz Haroon.
```